# Movie Metadata Storage

Tags: c#-4.0, metadata, movie, avi, imdb

Assuming I can query IMDB etc successfully and retrieve metadata for an avi.  Is there an existing file format for that metadata to store beside the avi?  I can create my own XML/JSON based mymovie2010.avi.metadata file, but I wonder if someone has created an interchange.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using the raw JSON from http://www.imdbapi.com/
Since the request/response was easy enough to get.  I store it next to the video in an imdb.txt. To be used for further processing later.